# php mktime() or uniqid()

Tags: php, duplicates, unique-key

I am using one of these to create a serial key.
I would like to know md5(uniqid()) or md5(mktime()) better to be use?

Which one has a less change to get a duplicated key?

Comment: Sidenote: Use `time()` instead of `mktime()` :)

Comment: Both ...  One will prevent duplicates by default .. The other will prevent duplicates based on the fact mktime() (I would use microtime() though) will never be the same ...

Comment: @Zak: do you think 2 things can't happen in the same microsecond?

Comment: @Yafa Su: Neither create serial keys.

Comment: @symcbean that's debatable, but `uniqid()` is based on `microtime()` so http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php  ... The question is which would have less chance ...  The answer is niether ..  There was no mention of "is there a better way?"

Comment: @Zak: uniqid() is *based* on microtime() - it combines this with a random value to make collisions less likely. i.e. uniqid() is much less likely to produce a collision

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`md5(uniqid("", true))` is the better method.  `time()` and `mktime()` are accurate to one second, so two executions within the same clock second would produce duplicate keys.

Comment: Actually, `uniqid` is based on microtime(), according to the manual. So yes, it is better in this case.

Comment: @lethal-guitar Partly, but microtime goes down to microseconds, and the second param true increases entropy.

Comment: generating an md5 hash adds nothing here part from slowing down the code and making the key larger.